# JSP doesn't open images, CSS ou JS

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, jstl

Good morning,

I try put CSS, JS and IMGs on my JSP, but doesn't work, but its strange because I use c:url da "jstl/core"

I'm use JSP, jstl and servlet, no frameworks.

[image: structure]

```
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<%@taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>
<%@taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/fmt" prefix="fmt" %>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>    
<head>
            <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
            <title>clientes atuantes</title>
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="<c:url value="/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css"/>">
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="<c:url value="/css/layout.css"/>">
            <script type="text/javascript" src="<c:url value="/bootstrap/js/jquery-1.12.0.js" />"></script>
            <script type="text/javascript" src="<c:url value="/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js" />"></script>
        </head>
        <body>

            <main>
                <div class="col-md-12">
                    <div class="panel panel-default espacamentoExterno5">

                        <div class="panel-body">
                            <p><img src="<c:url value="/img/ativo.gif"/>" /> ativo</p>
                            <p><img src="<c:url value="/img/congelado.gif"/>" /> congelado</p>
                            <p><img src="<c:url value="/img/cancelado.gif"/>" /> cancelado</p>

                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </main>
        </body>
```

Comment: Did you checked with your browser console for any path error(s)?

Comment: `<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>` Make sure you have attached this line as a first line of your jsp.

Comment: I'm using this taglib